# Infinite square grid of two different resistors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

We have always heard about infinite square grid of identical resistors, in which the equivalent resistance is easly derived by simmetry consideration. However, how would we compute (or at least upper and lower bound) the equivalent resistance between two adjacent vertices of an infinite square grid in which the value of all vertical resistors is $R$, and that of all horizontal resistors is $r$?

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps draw a diagram so one can see between which points you want to measure the resistance?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an answer, but I think it'd be a miracle if it worked out to be something nice by symmetry.